# upgrade version jhipster without OpenID

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jhipster

I Have a project with JHIPSTER 4.8.2.

I would upgrade jhipster (to go to spring boot 2) but I would keep home-made OAuth2  because I have several customer on production.

Is it possible? Or should I migrate to spring boot 2 manually?

Thank you

Comment: Manually is the safe approach, Our team usually do generate a new jhipster project and then use compare tools to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will do manually ...